# Why does aspnet_regsql create phantom tables? Is it corrupt?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, asp.net-membership

Whenever I run aspnet_regsql to create a default Membership schema in a new database, it adds a bunch of extra tables from a previous project of mine... Ones that don't have anything to do with membership. The ASP.NET membership tables work fine, I just can't figure out where these phantom tables are coming from.

Could the stored procedure have become corrupt? Any idea where to read it's contents?

Many thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the tables aren't added in at DB creation time as you previously accidentally added then to the model database?

Comment: Thanks Martin- They are in the model database. I don't have any idea what that is, so I'll have to research it. Many thanks!

Comment: That's the template database that new DBs are based off. You can add utility procs in there if you want them auto added to all new DBs for example.

Answer (score -2):

You can find your schema with tables in server explorer

Adjust your connection with -C parameter

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms229862%28v=vs.80%29.aspx